# How to get checkins of a user's particular friend from foursquare?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, foursquare

I am trying to get checkin information of a user's particular friend in my application. In application, user authenticates to foursquare at the start which make me able to get his/her friend list.

I am getting the friend list with this API end point : **https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/friends**. According to documentation it's response should include user objects which should have include checkins field but it seems there is no checkins field in the response. I can get other informations like first name, bio etc.

I also tried this API endpoint with user ID of friend which I want to get information of **https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/USER_ID/checkins** but it returns an error states that I am not authorized for getting this information.

What am I doing wrong? Should I be authorized for this information since the information is about checkins of user's friends?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2 check this link may be it will helpful to u....... https://github.com/baztokyo/foursquare-ios-api

Comment: Thank you for your answer. These API's are also using second API endpoint that I stated. So they would give the same error.

Comment: You should be authorize first and get access token

Comment: Actually I am doing that. I can get the friend list response without problem (using access token). That's why I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't a use case that's supported very well by the API. The way to see a list of check-ins of a particular user is through [users/self/checkins](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins). This will return the check-ins of the owner of the [OAuth](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) token that made the call.

Comment: Why no support for getting the public checkins of my friends through the API, when I can see my friend's checkins through the mobile app or web interface: http://support.foursquare.com/entries/23297816-Who-can-see-my-check-ins-?

Answer (score 0):

As stated here https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins:

> USER_ID   | self | For now, only self is supported